# How to use the non-const getter if there's a const one too?

Tags: c++, getter, const-cast

If I have a class with getters of return type both const and non-const, how can I use the non-const one?

The class (*MeshManipulator.h*):

```
namespace vortex::meshSculptEngine
{
    class MeshManipulator
    {
    public:
        ...
        topologyMesh::Mesh* getMesh();
        const topologyMesh::Mesh* getMesh() const;
        ...
    };
}
```

The code where I want to use the Mesh (*SimpleMeshCorrector.cpp*):

```
void SimpleMeshCorrector::smoothBoundaryLoops(float distance)
{
    if (!_boundaryLoops.empty()) {
        Mesh* mesh = getEngine()->getManipulator()->getMesh();
        ...
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> A value of type "const vortex::topologyMesh::Mesh*" cannot be used to
> initialize an entity of type "vortex::topologyMesh::Mesh*"

I can use `const_cast` but I just don't feel that this is the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: Do not use const_cast. What does the "getManipulator" return?
Provide minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Probably either `getEngine()` or `getManipulator()` return a pointer to `const`. Either change that (and the non-const version will be used) or do the `const_cast` (which is the wrong way to solve it).

Comment: @bielu000 It returns a const MeshManipulator* object

Comment: And that's the problem. You cannot call a non-const method on a const object.

Comment: Then you have your answer. MeshManiupulator* is a pointer to const object, then when you call getMesh, const overload will be used

Comment: @Friedrich So I should change the MeshManipulator getter to return a pointer to non-const object? And what if I am using an API and can't change this? I am just curious

Comment: Either you accept what the API gives you and that you should not change the `Mesh` object (there's probably a reason for it) or you `const_cast` at your own risk. Depending on what you want to do, you might also copy the `Mesh` object and manipulate your copy.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys for your time, it helps me a lot! Can you post it as an answer to accept it as a solution?

Comment: Do all your `getX` methods have both const and non-const versions? I mean `getEngine()` could return non-const engine, and so on...

Comment: @Quimby No, only the MeshManipulator class has const and non-const getters for Mesh object, all the others have only const getters.

Comment: I find this convention very clear: `get()` (const) and `get_mutable()` (by reference or non-const pointer).

Comment: @nomoresigsegv Sorry, can you explain it a little bit more? I just don't really understand what do you mean about this

Comment: @nomoresigsegv I think I get it

Comment: What @nomoresigsegv meant is that - instead of having a const and a non-const method of the same name - they should have different names, e.g. `get() const` and `get_mutable()` (non-const). This makes constness explicit.

Comment: @Friedrich thank you for your help, now it's clear! After this problem I can really appreciate the value of this convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause is (as clarified in comments) that `getManipulator()` returns a `const MeshManipulator*`. On a `const` object, only methods declared `const` can be called. Thus, the `const` getter is always called and never the non-`const` version.

Depending on the context, there are three ways to go on:

- Use (or write) a method that returns a mutable `MeshManipulator*`.
- Copy the `const Mesh*` to a local, mutable object.
- Use `const_cast<Mesh*>` to be able to mutate the object in place. This, however, defeats the purpose of constness. What's more, if the object pointed to was declared `const` this will result in undefined behavior. So use with care.

Comment: No, the third is not close to acceptable. It is inviting UB to come screaming at you.

Comment: @PasserBy I agree it should not be done unless you know what you're doing (same goes for my first suggestion, btw). What do you suggest? How can I improve this answer?

Comment: The first is fine and has plenty of legitimate use cases, what's your objection to it? `const_cast` is not. Mutating a `const` declared object is UB.

Comment: @PasserBy I edited my post to address the danger of UB. Please let me know if there are further issues. My objection to the first one is that there has to be a reason for declaring anything `const`. Throwing it away because it's inconvenient may cause side effects. So you have to do your homework before doing it. Same as with `const_cast`.